# Can I use tests written with Nette Tester with Jenkins

Tags: php, unit-testing, jenkins, nette, nette-tester

I need to make a continuous integration mechanism with some framework. The first on my mind was Jenkins but the whole project what I wanna test is written in Nette framework. So I want to  use Nette Tester but all videos about the topic are using PHPUnit. Is it possible to use Nette Tester with jenkins or should I search for something different. Or maybe I should use PHPUnit instead ?

Comment: When you creating Jenkins Build, you need to specify PHPUnit command which Jenkins run. It's same way with Nette Tester. Try read the docs for using with command line: https://github.com/nette/tester